# list index out of range for while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def main():
    infile = open('charge_accounts.txt', 'r')
    chargeAccounts = infile.readlines()

    index = 0
    while index < len(chargeAccounts):
        chargeAccounts[index] = chargeAccounts[index].rstrip('\n')
        index += 1

    userAccount = input("Please enter a charge account number: ")

    count = 0
    while userAccount != chargeAccounts[count] or chargeAccounts[count] == chargeAccounts[17]:
        count += 1


    if chargeAccounts[index] == userAccount:
        print("The account number", userAccount, "is in the list.")
    else:
        print("The account number", userAccount, "in not in the list.")


main()
```

I'm trying to make a code in python that has the user input a number and checks to see if that number is in a list. When I try to run this code, I get an error that says that the list index is out of range in the while loop. There are only 18 items in the list, and I have the while loop set to terminate at 17(which should be 18 in the list).
Edit: It also doesn't work if the while loop is set to `chargeAccounts[count] != chargeAccounts[17]:`

Here's the exact error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/CPT 168/Ch 7/AndrewBroughton_Chapter7_Excersizes/7-5/7-5.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:/CPT 168/Ch 7/AndrewBroughton_Chapter7_Excersizes/7-5/7-5.py", line 13, in main
    while userAccount != chargeAccounts[count] or chargeAccounts[count] != chargeAccounts[17]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here's the content of the original text file:

```
5658845
4520125
7895122
8777541
8451277
1302850
8080152
4562555
5552012
5050552
7825877
1250255
1005231
6545231
3852085
7576651
7881200
4581002
```

Comment: you have several while loops, post your exact error code and make the problem reproductible by providing us the original data.   It seems you increment count without checking that it is below the length of chargeAccount. You should check that before the other conditions of the while loop.

Comment: `chargeAccounts[17]` smells bad.

Comment: So what is the value of `len(chargeAccounts)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while loop will keep looping as long as its condition is `True`.

```
count = 0
while userAccount != chargeAccounts[count] or chargeAccounts[count] == chargeAccounts[17]:
    count += 1
```

If I enter an invalid `userAccount` to your program, the first part of the condition `userAccount != chargeAccounts[count]` is always going to be `True`. That makes the entire condition `True`, since you're using `or` logic.

Furthermore, if you want to check to see if you've reached the end of a list, you don't have to check the contents of the last list element (`chargeAccounts[count] == chargeAccounts[17]`). Check the length instead (`count == len(chargeAccounts)`).

To fix this, change that loop condition to something like

```
while count < len(chargeAccounts) and userAccount != chargeAccounts[count]:
```

(I'm not sure if this is exactly what you need, because I don't really follow the logic of your program. This should get you past the current error, though.)

Comment: That fixed the while loop, but now I'm getting the same error for "if chargeAccounts[count] == userAccount:
It works if I input the right number, but not a wrong number.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamBroughton `print` the values of `index` and `count` to find where they're going out of range of your list.

Comment: It says the count is 18, weird.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it by putting in an if statement that changes the count to 0 if it's above 17. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You get the error at the string `if chargeAccounts[index] == userAccount:` because `index` is already bigger than the index of the last element of the list (because you left the loop with this `index` above).

I would recommend you to follow a few rules to work with lists that could save you from similar errors with indices.

1. Use `for`-loop instead of `while`-loop, if you lineary go through each element.
2. Use `break` if you want to leave the loop and keep the index

So you code may look like this:

```
with open('charge_accounts.txt', 'r') as infile:
    chargeAccounts = infile.readlines()

for index in range(len(chargeAccounts)):
    chargeAccounts[index] = chargeAccounts[index].strip()

userAccount = input("Please enter a charge account number: ")

found = False
for chargeAccount in chargeAccounts:
    if chargeAccount = userAccount:
        found = True
        break

if found:
    print("The account number", userAccount, "is in the list.")
else:
    print("The account number", userAccount, "in not in the list.")
```